# Workbox: writing regular expression for url patterns

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, workbox, sw-precache

I am trying to precache routes. I have successfully precaches the homepage using

```
 workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(['/']);
```

and this to match route for homepage

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
 /^\/$/,
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
    cacheName: 'static-resources',
  })
);
```

I still have other top level routes i will like to match but not sure how.

```
localhost/subcategory //subcategory and slug attached to it
localhost/product  //product and slug attached to it
localhost/product-single // and slug attached to it
```

How do i write the regular expression for the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use https://regex101.com/ to help you achieve what you want.

A regex like `^localhost(\/.+)?$` should do the trick